# How can I identify the component responsible fro reordering keyboard input?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, compiz

I have Ubuntu 14.04 running on a Dell Latitude 13 laptop.
When I launch Chromium and open several pages from stackexchange in different tabs. Any text I type in will frequently have characters showing up in a different order from how they were typed. For example, this paragraph actually showed up as:

> I have Ubuntu 14.04 runnign on  aDell Latitude 1 3laptop.
>   Whne I alucnh Chormium na dopne several pages form tsackexchnag ei ndiffreent tabs. Any text I type in will ferwuqently have cahracters shwoing up in  adifferent ofrdre form hwo htye weer ytped. For exmapel, thsi apragraph actually shwoed up as

As you can imagine having to manually fix that every time it happens can be very frustrating. The behavior looks as if some layer in the software stack is inserting key presses into a stack rather than a queue, and if they are not consumed as quickly as they arrive, they show up in the wrong order.

This only happens sporadically, and seems to happen more often when Chromium is swapping a lot. I have not been able to identify which layer of the software stack is causing the problem. Is there any additional debugging/logging I could enable to show me in which order characters show up at different layers in the software stack?

**What I have tried so far**

By sending alternating `STOP` and `CONT` signals to an xterm, I was able to slow down xterm just enough to reproduce the symptom. Since reordering of keyboard input is not supposed to happen even if xterm is frozen for a little bit, I think it is safe to conclude that the flaw is not in Chromium or stackexchange, but rather in some software being involved in both cases.

In order to rule out the possibility that it may be a flaw in the keyboard hardware, I tested with synthetic key presses.

```
sleep 10 ; for K in {a..z} ; do xdotool type "$K" ; sleep 0.2 ; done
```

With that command I was able to reproduce the problem. On one occasion the keys showed up in the order `abcdefghlmkjpnioqrstuvwxyz`. So when it also happens with keypresses generated by `xdotool`, it cannot be a flaw in the keyboard or keyboard controller.

If I speed up the input produced using xdotool even further, it causes the xterm to lock up.

Seeing an xterm lock up when keyboard input arrives quickly is something I have seen even without artificially slowing it down using STOP signals. When I do see xterm lock up like that, it usually keeps happening after I kill the xterm and start a new one. That problem persists until I run `compiz --replace`. After running that command everything runs faster and xterm no longer locks up at least for the first few days.

So there is some evidence suggesting that the two problems are related and somehow has something to do with `compiz`, but I don't have any solid evidence to back up that suspicion.

Comment: Oh man, this is not going to be simple :( Does it happen only in chromium?

Comment: @terdon By sending alternating `STOP` and `CONT` signals to an xterm I managed to slow down an xterm enough to reproduce the symptom.

Comment: OK but that was asking for it :) Does it happen naturally in anything else but chromium? I'm trying to understand if it's a chromium issue or a more general one.

Comment: @terdon To find out whether the problem was related to the keyboard hardware itself, I tried with synthetic keyboard input produced using xdotool as well.

Comment: @terdon I have updated my question with results of experiments performed so far. I see a possible connection with a `compiz` performance issue.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same problem with chromium on a first-gen Lenovo X1 Carbon. I'm using the i3 windowmanager. Could it be something to do with Xorg?

Comment: @Logan Am I understanding correctly that you have seen the issue in a setup which does not use compiz?

Comment: Could you install another desktop environment (openbox, gnome, kde)?  also could  you post list all ppa you are using related to xorg, drivers, desktop...?

Comment: @Sneetsher How do I get the list of ppa?

Comment: @kasperd, you may use `grep -r ppa /etc/apt/sources.list*`

Comment: @Sneetsher The string `ppa` is not found in any of those files.

Comment: @kasperd, Could you install openbox it is a light DE. So we know if a DE/compiz problem or xorg/driver problem.

Comment: @Sneetsher I'll give it a try. It will take a while before I am certain whether it makes a difference, since the problem doesn't show up right after login.